# curl does not support http2 on mac

Tags: curl, homebrew, http2

I've got the latest version of curl and still not seeing http2 show up as a feature. I've followed steps around related questions, but still out of luck.

```
$ /usr/local/Cellar/curl/7.43.0/bin/curl -V
curl 7.43.0 (x86_64-apple-darwin14.3.0) libcurl/7.43.0 SecureTransport zlib/1.2.5
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz UnixSockets
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 30):

`brew info curl` lists the required flags to enable that feature.

`brew reinstall curl --with-openssl --with-nghttp2` will update your installation.

Comment: @MarkFine : If it solves the problem, could you validate that answer with the green check?

Answer (score 26):

The Homebrew team recently [removed all options for the `curl` formula](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/31510), but the `curl-openssl` formula has HTTP/2 enabled.

```
brew install curl-openssl
```

Answer (score 10):

By default, `curl` is not compiled with `nghttp2`. As [explained in this article](https://simonecarletti.com/blog/2016/01/http2-curl-macosx/), you need to recompile it passing the `--with-nghttp2` flag and link it (to replace the original `curl` shipped with Mac OS X.

```
# install cURL with nghttp2 support
$  brew install curl --with-nghttp2

# link the formula to replace the system cURL
$  brew link curl --force

# now reload the shell
```

Comment: Any issues overriding the system curl?